# Why the - pyenv: no such command 'shell' error

Tags: pyenv

This seems pretty basic so why the `no such command` error:

```
$ pyenv shell
pyenv: no such command `shell`
```

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-shell

Comment: Please ensure you do the steps 1, 2 *and* 3 detailed here: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout

Comment: It solved the same issue on my machine, thank you. @Paolo

Answer (score 0):

pyenv shell switch your python locally (current shell session) to a specific version. You should run it by following the version you've already instlled.
To check the current python you are using and the versions installed:

```
pyenv version  #return the version you are using
pyenv versions  # return all versions installed
```

You can then set the python version for your current shell session

```
pyenv shell 3.6.4    #3.6.4 is one of the installed python version
```